# UIButton wont show title

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIbutton title that I set with

```
[[buttons objectAtIndex:selectedButtonTag] setTitle:file forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This for some reason doesnt force the button to change title.

When I print the title of the button with

```
UIButton *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:selectedButtonTag];
NSLog(@"button text is %@",button.titleLabel.text);
```

It actually  prints the previously set title.

Is there some refresh call on the UI or why isnt the button displaying the title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To anyone having the same issue and has checked all other options. Make sure the png you use for the UIButton is set in the background image field, rather than the image field.

Comment: I have the same problem but my buttons have no png... all of these questions include background images, but not mine...

Comment: @Morkrom - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: great.. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the title of the button in Normal & Highlighted state also please make sure that image set to the button is set as its background image rather than image

Answer (score 0):

If you button is selected or highlighted and you've specifically set a title for one of those states, it will not show the UIControlStateNormal title.

If that's the case, I'd suggest either avoiding setting the title for anything other than the normal state, or else set the title for all potential states of your button.

Comment: Its a custom UIButton outlet linked in IB. The button has an image set to a png. Other than that there is nothing else. All the states have been left to default.

Comment: lame issue. The png was set to the image, not the background image. z order issue. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Ah! No, I wouldn't delete it. Just answer it yourself & accept your answer; I've had your bug before and someone might find it useful.

Comment: Though, your answer doesn't explain why titleLabel.text isn't updated. You might need a layoutIfNeeded call for that.

Comment: It was being updated. But behind the png set on the image attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just so all of us don't have to google how to set background image :)

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```